# Can I use the Azure Data Studio SQL kernel with the jupyter nbconvert command to execute and convert a notebook to HTML?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, nbconvert, azure-data-studio

I am working with Azure Data Studio and I have a notebook (`notebook.ipynb`) that uses the SQL kernel in Azure Data Studio. I want to programmatically execute the notebook and convert it to HTML using the `jupyter nbconvert` command. However, I am unsure if it's possible to use the SQL kernel from Azure Data Studio with `jupyter nbconvert`.

Is it feasible to run the following command to execute and convert the notebook to HTML, with SQL being the kernel used in Azure Data Studio?

```
jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=SQL --execute --to html notebook.ipynb
```

If not, what alternatives or approaches can I take to programmatically execute the notebook and export its results to HTML while using the Azure Data Studio SQL kernel? I am currently running the notebook manually and exporting it to HTML without the `--execute` flag.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this. Thank you!

edit:

When I run `jupyter kernelspec list` this is what I get:

```
Available kernels:
  powershell       C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\powershell
  pysparkkernel    C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\pysparkkernel
  sparkkernel      C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\sparkkernel
  sparkrkernel     C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\sparkrkernel
  python3          C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

So, Azure Data Studio's SQL kernel is not listed.